# Saving/Organizing/Searching Outlook E-mail outside of Outlook

Tags: outlook, email

My company requires me to use Outlook for my E-mail.  Outlook does virtually nothing the way I want to do it and it frustrates me greatly.  (I'm not trying to start a flame war here, it must do exactly what thousands of CEO's want it to do, but I'm not a CEO.)

I would like to be able to automatically extract the thousands of E-mails and attachments currently in my Outlook account and save them in my own alternative storage format where I can easily search them and organize them the way I want.  (I'm not requesting suggestions for the new format.)

Maybe some nice open source program already can do this... that would be great.  Please let me know.

Otherwise, **how can I obtain the message content and the attachments without going through the huge collection manually?**  Even if I could only get the message content and the names of the attachments, that would be sufficient.  Is there documentation of the Outlook mail storage format?  Is there a way to query Outlook for the data?

Maybe there is an alternative approach I haven't considered?

My preferred language to do this is C#, but I can use others if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) is the best thing currently to use that I have found.  It will allow you to get into the messages and extract the attachments and the message bodies.  i am using it now to do just that.

Here is some code I use in a class.  I included the constructor and the processing function I use to save off the attachments.  I cut out the code that is specific to my needs but you can get an idea of what to use here.

```
    private RDOSession _MailSession = new RDOSession();
    private RDOFolder _IncommingInbox;
    private RDOFolder _ArchiveFolder;
    private string _SaveAttachmentPath;

    public MailBox(string Logon_Profile, string IncommingMailPath, 
                   string ArchiveMailPath, string SaveAttPath)
    {
        _MailSession.Logon(Logon_Profile, null, null, true, null, null);
        _IncommingInbox = _MailSession.GetFolderFromPath(IncommingMailPath);
        _ArchiveFolder = _MailSession.GetFolderFromPath(ArchiveMailPath);
        _SaveAttachmentPath = SaveAttPath;
    }
public void ProcessMail()
        {

            foreach (RDOMail msg in _IncommingInbox.Items)
            {
                foreach (RDOAttachment attachment in msg.Attachments)
                {
                    attachment.SaveAsFile(_SaveAttachmentPath + attachment.FileName);
                    }
                }
                if (msg.Body != null)
                {
                    ProcessBody(msg.Body);
                }

            }

        }
```

**edit:**
This is how I call it and what is passed

```
MailBox pwaMail = new MailBox("Self Email User", @"\\Mailbox - Someone\Inbox",
                              @"\\EMail - Incomming\Backup", @"\\SomePath");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract your e-mails take a look at 
Outlook Email Extractor
at codeproject
http://69.10.233.10/KB/dotnet/OutlookEmailExtractor.aspx

rob
www.filefriendly.com